# Ruby RSA encryption/decryption

Tags: c#, ruby

So I have a legacy .net tool that encrypts/decrypts a custom file and I would like to convert this from .net to ruby but I'm not 100% sure how the values are to be set in ruby.

Here is my C# code:

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
rsa.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(LicenseUtils.PRIVATE_KEY_DATA));
var readBuffer = new byte[LicenseUtils.READ_BUFFER_LEN];
int bytesRead;
byte[] hash = ....;
byte[] result = rsa.Decrypt(hash, true);
var signature = rsa.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
....
```

LicenseUtils.PRIVATE_KEY_DATA is a string of length 1564

I have been looking at using ruby openssl but I am not fully following it. As most of the documentation refers to reading from a file.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you wanted to convert this code to **ruby**?

Comment: "I would like to convert this to .net" but "how the values are to be set in ruby." - it's unclear whether you want this code in c#, .net or ruby. Can you please clarify what exactly you want? :)

Comment: Sorry meant to be "from" the .net code